# React.js Simple Slider

Tags: reactjs

i have imported this simple slider and it shows and everything but my images arent showing, i have everything imported and i am sure my paths to the images are correct but the slider just shows black, heres my code.

heres the const.

```
 const images = [
        { url: "../images/1.jpg" },
        { url: "../images/2.jpg" },
        { url: "../images/3.jpg" },
        { url: "../images/4.jpg" },
      ];
```

and heres the return.

```
<SimpleImageSlider
                
                    width={1900}
                    height={700}
                    images={images}
                    showBullets={true}
                    showNavs={true}
                />
```

Comment: Based on the code you have shown us it should work correctly. So either the URLs are incorrect, or there is some other piece of code that is creating the problem.

Comment: i also changed the urls but there was no luck , it gets picked up as a element in the css uppon inspect but thats about it, thanks for your input !

Comment: Right click on the slider to inspect element and see what is going on with the image path when the browser renders it

Comment: @Matt I was just about to write pretty much the same thing. What happens if you open the URL (that you see in the html when you inspect element) in a new tab?

Comment: when i inspect in my browser i see the image url inside of the css element so its there but nothing is seen or renders out

Comment: Try using images={Object.values(images)}